# ASP.Net Web API exception filter, logging to database failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In our ASP.Net Web API application we are planning to handle the handle exceptions via Global exception filter attribute, as detailed in the following [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling).

We are planning to log the exception to in multiple medium like database, files using NLog. what baffles me is a medium like Database, if we log and there's an exception like database down, connection timeout and multiple others, then it will go in infinite loop, as it will keep try to log the exception, which will be keep returning an exception.

Is there a mechanism to restrict it 1 or 2 tries and after that fail silently, not enter an infinite loop, any pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We are planning to log the exception to in multiple medium like
>   database, files using NLog. what baffles me is a medium like Database,
>   if we log and there's an exception like database down, connection
>   timeout and multiple others, then it will go in infinite loop, as it
>   will keep try to log the exception, which will be keep returning an
>   exception.

That's why you should make absolutely sure that your logging code never fails. For example by wrapping it in a `try/catch` statement.

Comment: If I am using Exception Filter, do I have the provision to use a Try Catch block, since I am overriding an OnException method which automatically gets triggered on exception, until and unless I start checking the specific error messages, I cannot stop that looping. There could be hundred of such messages, what's the way out

Comment: does your message means that in OnException override method, I include the logging inside a Try Catch and this would take care of exception in that part, will not reinvoke the OnException call as I am expecting